# Using array page name together with page id to deregister script

Tags: functions, pages, wp-enqueue-script, array, id

If I use this:

```
if (is_page(array(blabla-test-page, 20726, 20720, 38881))) {wp_deregister_script( 'gdsr_script' );
}
```

the `blabla-test-page` looks like it overrides different pages, even if certain pages have not the same `body class`.

For example: the page with `id` 5555 has no body class `blabla-test-page`, but for some reason, it deregisters this script too... If I remove `blabla-test-page` and change it to the ID number it has, 5555 will not be affected... How can this be happening? How should I use page name and page id together?

FYI: in the `codex`, it says `is_page( array( 42, 'about-me', 'About Me And Joe' ) )`, but when I do this, the page-named class won't deregister the scripts. I think that this is very weird.

Comment: `blabla-test-page` should be in quotes: `"blabla-test-page"`.

Comment: I just edited my question before you commented. I tried that, but then it does not deregister the scripts of the page with the page-name....

Comment: Are you running(hooking) it after registering the scripts?

Comment: I am doing this before deregistering `add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregister_scripts', 100 );`